# jQuery Selection & Filtering Problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Greetings,

I am trying to append a new comment to a Comments UL, in a string of parent posts, using jQuery. I cannot seem to figure out how to append to the parent post's comments UL, here is the HTML -

```
<div class="statusUpdate-DIV">
        <div class="statusUpdate-middle">
            <span class="statusUpdate-timestamp"><?php echo date("M d, y g:i a", strtotime($row['timestamp']));?></span>
            <span class="statusUpdate-title"><?php echo $row['title'];?></span>
            <?php echo $row['body'];?>
            <div class="commentsDIV" id="status<?php echo $row['id'];?>">
                <ul class="commentsBlock">
                    <li><strong>This is a comment</strong> comment here</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="postCommentDIV">
                <span class="commentHeader">Comment</span>
                <form name="commentForm" class="postCommentFORM" method="post" action="">
                    <textarea rows="3" cols="63" class="commentBody" name="commentBody"></textarea>
                    <input type="submit" value="Post"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I am trying to append the value of `commentBody` (form textarea) to `commentsBlock` (UL). I was able to retrieve the value of `commentBody` with the following script, issue is appending it to the previous commentsBlock UL:

```
    //This is just a test to make sure the value of .commentBody is being retrieved
$(".postCommentDIV form").submit(function() {
                    var comment = $(this).find(".commentBody").val();
                    alert(comment);
                    return false;
            });
```

Thanks..

Comment: Just to clarify, there are several `statusUpdate-DIV`'s on the same page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is to add this where the alert currently is:

```
// Create the <li> containing the comment
var commentLi = $("<li>").text(comment);
// Travel up DOM tree to the closest statusUpdate-DIV, then back down to append
$(this).closest("statusUpdate-DIV").find(".commentsBlock").append(commentLi);
```

jQuery's `.text()` will automatically escape any HTML in the comment.

Comment: Thanks! This worked great, just had to change $(this).closest("statusUpdate-DIV") to $(this).closest(".statusUpdate-middle"). Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).closest('.statusUpdate-middle').find('.commentsBlock').append(comment);
```

- the [`closest()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method to get the nearest `statusUpdate-middle` ancestor
- the [`find()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method to find the nested `commentsBlock`
- the [`append()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/append/) method to append the comment.

Comment: Of course! closest()! Totally forgot about that, I was trying to figure it out using parents() and getting ready to pull my hair out. Thanks very much - this would have been the chosen answer but it did not seem to append a new li to the commentsBlock UL. I would have figured this out but Box9 provided a full solution out of the...box, as it were. ;) Thanks for the reminder and references.

Comment: @NightMICU: Yeah, I left the `<li>` creation up to you. FYI, to use `.parents()`, you'd simply do `.parents('.statusUpdate-middle:first')`. The `:first` is just in case you have nested elements with the same class name.

Comment: Great information! And I wish Box9 didn't make it so simple, should have had a little more to figure out lol

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do something like this:

```
    $(".postCommentDIV form").submit(function() {
              var comment = $(this).find(".commentBody").val();
              $('<li>').text(comment).appendTo('.commentsDIV .commentsBlock');
              return false;
    });
```

Pay attention in using class for performance issues, better to use id to identify a unique block, as the  containing the comments, so you could do .appendTo('#commentsBlock').

Comment: Ah very good. +1 for performance consideration. Part of the issue is that there are multiple identical post DIVs, each with their own comments and comment forms - just like here on Stack Overflow. So I could not reference `#commentsBlock` since there would be several on the same page. I could, however, assign a unique ID to each post and then retrieve that.. would this help or would it be six in one, half dozen in the other?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$(".postCommentDIV form").submit(function() {
var comment = $(this).find(".commentBody").val();
$(this).find(".commentsBlock").append("<ul><strong>" + comment + "</strong></ul>");
return false;
});
```

Comment: In this case `.find()` won't work to get the `.commentsBlock` because it isn't inside the `<form>`.